# Order not placed in Server with Product price zero

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, payment

Order not placed in Server with Product price zero. Whereas in local server order placed successfully. Only zero priced products are not getting placed in server. What might be the issue? Help me to find out the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the error message or log messages >

Comment: In the log file, I didn't see any error. But it is showing "We can't place the order error" while placing the order.

Answer (score 1):

You can not able to placed order of Product price zero it cause of `Zero Subtotal Checkout` Payment method. You have to need enable first in server and check. I guess in your local `Zero Subtotal Checkout` Payment method already enable check in local and server.

You can check below configuration in admin for `Zero Subtotal Checkout` Payment method.

**Step 1) Login to admin.**

**Step 2) Stores >> Configuration >> SALES >> Payment Methods**

**Step 3) Open `Zero Subtotal Checkout` Payment method and Enabled it and save the Configuration.**

Now clear the cache `php bin/magento cache:flush` and place the order.

Hope it help!